# What instrumentation and/or measurement is likely being shown in this video of giant Siberian craters/sinkholes?

Tags: measurements, instrumentation, field-measurements, identify-this-object

The RT video [The Permafrost Mystery: scientists explore giant Yamal Sinkhole](https://youtu.be/jc-FFhdNG9A?t=840) (with English subtitles) shows scientists exploring the formation. In one scene after about `14:00` two scientists are deploying a device made of two perhaps 30 meter or more long wires(?) separated by about 1.2 meters, held apart by a rigid brace. One scientist holds some electronic equipment with a cable going down to one side of the brace.

Two screenshots are shown below. I can't tell if these long green wires go down into the hole as well or if those are something different, but I think they do, eventually.

Can anyone identify this instrument and what it measures, or at least provide some insightful educated speculation?

---

Potentially related [Detecting and Mapping Gas Emission Craters on the Yamal and Gydan Peninsulas, Western Siberia](https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3263/11/1/21)

[image: screenshot from the RT video "The Permafrost Mystery: scientists explore giant Yamal Sinkhole"]

[image: screenshot from the RT video "The Permafrost Mystery: scientists explore giant Yamal Sinkhole"]

Comment: There's a new one: https://earther.gizmodo.com/siberia-s-newest-exploding-crater-has-been-mapped-in-3d-1846288021

Comment: @KeithMcClary yikes! but very nice photos, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a geophysical method. But a wide variety of such methods have been applied to the Yamal crater by [Olenchenko et al. (2015)](http://izdatgeo.ru/pdf/earth_cryo/2015-4/84_eng.pdf):

> The complex of geophysical survey techniques included electrical resistivity tomography (ERT), near-field transient electromagnetic sounding (Transient Electro Magnetic (TEM) sounding), magnetic survey, and radioactivity survey.

I'd say it looks like the first one (ERT), but it's just an "educated speculation"! :)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, thanks! It could be something a little bit like (but not exactly) [this](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/17447/6031)?

Comment: Exactly, something like this! Also used by archaeologists.